# Optimise pivot table with many attribute columns

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas

I'm using Excel pivot table to give users access to customer data that's stored in a SSAS cube, and finding that the data refresh time is exorbitant. The pivot table shows total revenue from each customer, and includes the following on the rows (from two separate dimensions):

- Customer ID
- Customer name
- phone
- email address
- a date indicating if/when the email address bounced
- address line 1
- address line 2
- address line 3
- address line 4
- address line 5
- a date indicating if/when the address failed
- a couple of T/F indicators

... and financial year on the columns.

You'll recognise that most of the customer attributes are not really grouping fields: only Customer ID and Year require data aggregation. But using SSAS and Excel in this way seems to necessitate all 13 attributes being treated as grouping columns and hence there are 13 levels of aggregation.

Consequently, with a subset of about 20,000 customers, it may take 30 minutes to refresh the pivot table. I think the majority of time is on the SSAS rather than Excel side, but I don't know if that's because the MDX Excel generates is crap or the structure of the cube is responsible.

How can this be optimised?

Comment: Is this SSAS multidimensional?  If so, can you create a pivot table for them that uses properties instead of attributes for the non-aggregatable fields?

Comment: That might be the hint I needed. I found some more details of that idea at http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DustinRyan/bidn-blog/2087/defining-member-properties-for-an-attribute-in-ssas-2008 and will investigate whether it helps.